# Why my components does not load?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and following a tutorial I was stopped on unexpected behavior my components does not get rendered. Here is the `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './css/style.css';

import App from './components/app';
import StorePicker from './components/storepicker';

import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = () => {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={StorePicker} />
                <Route path='/store/:storeid' component={App} />
            </Switch>
        )

}

render(<root/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

StorePicker.js

```
import React from 'react';

class StorePicker extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="store-selector">
                <h2>Please enter a store</h2>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Store Name"/>
                <button type="submit">Visit Store</button>
            </form>
        )    
    }
}

export default StorePicker;
```

the navigation to `http://localhost:3000/` I see only the app background gray color and nothing get rendered. any advise ? The app is Compiled successfully! no errors.

Comment: I think it may be the lowercase `root`; I think it needs to be `Root`

Comment: This is right, `<root />` won't work. If you open DevTools, you will see a warning about this in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not rendering your app inside a router tag, see this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './css/style.css';

import App from './components/app';
import StorePicker from './components/storepicker';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Root = () => 
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={StorePicker} />
      <Route path='/store/:storeid' component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>;

render(<Root />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: Syntax error: D:/React/tut/store/src/index.js: Unterminated JSX contents (20:15) in line `render(<Root />, document.querySelector('#root'));` what is wrong with this line ?